# SQL Server - Complex Dynamic Pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two tables "Controls" and "ControlChilds"

Parent Table Structure:

```
Create table Controls(
    ProjectID Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ControlID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlCode Varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    ControlPoint Decimal NULL,
    ControlScore Decimal NULL,
    ControlValue Varchar(50)
)
```

Sample Data

```
ProjectID | ControlID | ControlCode | ControlPoint | ControlScore | ControlValue
P001        1           A            30.44            65           Invalid
P001        2           C            45.30            85           Valid
```

Child Table Structure:

```
Create table ControlChilds(
    ControlID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlChildID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlChildValue Varchar(200) NULL 
)
```

Sample Data

```
ControlID | ControlChildID | ControlChildValue
1           100              Yes
1           101              No
1           102              NA  
1           103              Others 
2           104              Yes
2           105              SomeValue
```

Output should be in a single row for a given ProjectID with all its Control values first & followed by child control values (based on the ControlCode (i.e.) ControlCode_Child (1, 2, 3...) and it should look like this

[image: Report format]

Also, I tried this PIVOT query and I am able to get the ChildControls table values but I dont know how to get the Controls table values.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT 
                        distinct ',' + 
                        QUOTENAME(ControlCode + '_Child' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY ControlCode ORDER BY ControlChildID) AS Varchar(25)))
                      FROM Controls C
                      INNER JOIN ControlChilds CC 
                      ON C.ControlID = CC.ControlID 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query ='SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT   
    (ControlCode + ''_Child'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY ControlCode ORDER BY ControlChildID) AS Varchar(25))) As Code,
        ControlChildValue
  FROM Controls AS C
  INNER JOIN ControlChilds AS CC ON C.ControlID = CC.ControlID
) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(ControlChildValue) 
  FOR Code IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p ; ';

 execute(@query);
```

Output I am getting:
[image]

Can anyone please help me on how to get the Controls table values in front of each ControlChilds table values?

Comment: `Controls.ProjectID` is defined as `INT` but its values is `P001`, which one is correct?

Comment: Good catch! Its a typo and it should be varchar.

Comment: Have you tried writing this as a static version first to get the logic correct?  This is sometimes much easier then trying to tackle a dynamic pivot immediately.

Comment: @bluefeet: No. I haven't tried that but based on some samples I did this. Also, I am really confused on how to transform two tables into a single row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a bit of a mess here because you have two tables in different structures and you want to pivot multiple columns.  I would first start out writing a static version of your query to get the logic correct, then go through the process of writing a dynamic version.

Since you want to pivot multiple columns you'll need to unpivot the several columns in the `Controls` table first, then pivot.  You've tagged this as SQL Server 2008, so you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the columns.

I'd suggest taking the following steps. First, unpivot the `controls` table:

```
select 
  ProjectId,
  col = ControlCode +'_'+col,
  val
from
(
  select 
    c.ProjectId,
    c.ControlCode,
    c.ControlPoint,
    c.ControlScore,
    c.ControlValue
  from controls c
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'ControlPoint', cast(controlpoint as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'ControlScore', cast(ControlScore as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'ControlValue', ControlValue
) c (col, val)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76778/12/0). This is going to convert your multiple rows into multiple columns similar to:

```
| PROJECTID |            COL |     VAL |
|-----------|----------------|---------|
|      P001 | A_ControlPoint |   30.44 |
|      P001 | A_ControlScore |   65.00 |
|      P001 | A_ControlValue | Invalid |
|      P001 | C_ControlPoint |   45.30 |
|      P001 | C_ControlScore |   85.00 |
|      P001 | C_ControlValue |   Valid |
```

Second, get the data from the `ControlChilds` table into a similar format but use your `row_number()` to assign a sequence for each child:

```
select 
  projectId,
  col = ControlCode+'_'+'Child'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
  ControlChildValue
from
(
  select c.ProjectId,
    c.ControlCode,
    cc.ControlChildValue,
    row_number() over(partition by c.ProjectId, c.ControlCode
                      order by cc.ControlChildId) seq
  from controls c
  inner join controlchilds cc
    on c.controlid = cc.controlid
) d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76778/13/0). This gets the data from this table in the format:

```
| PROJECTID |      COL | CONTROLCHILDVALUE |
|-----------|----------|-------------------|
|      P001 | A_Child1 |               Yes |
|      P001 | A_Child2 |                No |
|      P001 | A_Child3 |                NA |
|      P001 | A_Child4 |            Others |
|      P001 | C_Child1 |               Yes |
|      P001 | C_Child2 |         SomeValue |
```

Now, you can easily use `UNION ALL` between the two queries and apply the PIVOT function:

```
select ProjectId,
  A_ControlPoint, A_ControlScore, A_ControlValue,
  A_Child1, A_Child2, A_Child3, A_Child4,
  C_ControlPoint, C_ControlScore, C_ControlValue,
  C_Child1, C_Child2
from
(
  select 
    ProjectId,
    col = ControlCode +'_'+col,
    val
  from
  (
    select 
      c.ProjectId,
      c.ControlCode,
      c.ControlPoint,
      c.ControlScore,
      c.ControlValue
    from controls c
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'ControlPoint', cast(controlpoint as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'ControlScore', cast(ControlScore as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'ControlValue', ControlValue
  ) c (col, val)
  union all
  select 
    projectId,
    col = ControlCode+'_'+'Child'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    ControlChildValue
  from
  (
    select c.ProjectId,
      c.ControlCode,
      cc.ControlChildValue,
      row_number() over(partition by c.ProjectId, c.ControlCode
                        order by cc.ControlChildId) seq
    from controls c
    inner join controlchilds cc
      on c.controlid = cc.controlid
  ) d
) src
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (A_ControlPoint, A_ControlScore, A_ControlValue,
              A_Child1, A_Child2, A_Child3, A_Child4,
              C_ControlPoint, C_ControlScore, C_ControlValue,
              C_Child1, C_Child2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76778/14/0).

Now that you have the correct logic, you can convert this to a dynamic SQL version:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select ControlCode,
                        col = ControlCode +'_'+col,
                        seq, 
                        so
                      from controls
                      cross apply
                      (
                        select 'ControlPoint', 0, 0 union all
                        select 'ControlScore', 0, 1 union all
                        select 'ControlValue', 0, 2 
                      ) c (col, seq, so)
                      union all
                      select  ControlCode,
                        col = ControlCode+'_'+'Child'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                        seq, 
                        3
                      from
                      (
                        select ControlCode, 
                          row_number() over(partition by c.ProjectId, c.ControlCode
                                                  order by cc.ControlChildId) seq
                        from controls c
                        inner join controlchilds cc
                          on c.controlid = cc.controlid
                      ) d
                    ) src
                    group by ControlCode, seq, col, so
                    order by ControlCode, so, seq
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ProjectId, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select ProjectId,
                col = ControlCode +''_''+col,
                val
              from
              (
                select 
                  c.ProjectId,
                  c.ControlCode,
                  c.ControlPoint,
                  c.ControlScore,
                  c.ControlValue
                from controls c
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select ''ControlPoint'', cast(controlpoint as varchar(10)) union all
                select ''ControlScore'', cast(ControlScore as varchar(10)) union all
                select ''ControlValue'', ControlValue
              ) c (col, val)
              union all
              select 
                projectId,
                col = ControlCode+''_Child''+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                ControlChildValue
              from
              (
                select c.ProjectId,
                  c.ControlCode,
                  cc.ControlChildValue,
                  row_number() over(partition by c.ProjectId, c.ControlCode
                                    order by cc.ControlChildId) seq
                from controls c
                inner join controlchilds cc
                  on c.controlid = cc.controlid
              ) d
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db46/37/0).  I wrote the dynamic version to keep the columns in the order that you used in your sample. This can be done by using a sort order type of value.

This gives a final result of:

```
| PROJECTID | A_CONTROLPOINT | A_CONTROLSCORE | A_CONTROLVALUE | A_CHILD1 | A_CHILD2 | A_CHILD3 | A_CHILD4 | C_CONTROLPOINT | C_CONTROLSCORE | C_CONTROLVALUE | C_CHILD1 |  C_CHILD2 |
|-----------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------|-----------|
|      P001 |          30.44 |          65.00 |        Invalid |      Yes |       No |       NA |   Others |          45.30 |          85.00 |          Valid |      Yes | SomeValue |
```

Comment: Genius! Great explanation and you made this complex one look very simple.

Comment: @user972255 Happy to help, I must say this one took me a bit to tackle the right way but you including a lot of info in your question to solve it which helped considerably.

Comment: Now I have a requirement to show Child Comments for each child elements. For example, A_Child1, A_Child1Comments, A_Child2, A_Child2Comments etc... Another tricky thing is I need to show the comments only when they are not null otherwise I shouldn't show the column. Is this possible? I tried lot of things but the results are not accurate.

Comment: @user972255 I'd suggest posting a new question with the requirements, it would be too difficult to answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

To `PIVOT` your data you first need to `UNPIVOT` part of it, the part in the `Controls` table.

The preparation query become

```
SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + '_' + [Field] [Field], Value
FROM   (SELECT ProjectID
             , ControlCode
             , CAST(ControlPoint AS SQL_Variant) ControlPoint
             , CAST(ControlScore AS SQL_Variant) ControlScore
             , CAST(ControlValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlValue
        FROM Controls C) D
       UNPIVOT
       (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlPoint, ControlScore, ControlValue)) p
UNION ALL
SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + '_Child' + RowID [Field], Value
FROM   (SELECT C.ProjectID
             , C.ControlCode
             , RowID = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY CC.ControlID 
                       ORDER BY CC.ControlChildID) AS VARCHAR)
             , CAST(CC.ControlChildValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlChildValue
        FROM Controls C
             INNER JOIN ControlChilds CC ON C.ControlID = CC.ControlID) D
       UNPIVOT
       (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlChildValue)) p
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/438b5/12)</kbd>

to have the data in the format

```
PROJECTID | FIELD          | VALUE
----------+----------------+----------
P001      | A_ControlPoint | 30
P001      | A_ControlScore | 65
P001      | A_ControlValue | Invalid
P001      | C_ControlPoint | 45
P001      | C_ControlScore | 85
P001      | C_ControlValue | Valid
P001      | A_Child1       | Yes
P001      | A_Child2       | No
P001      | A_Child3       | NA
P001      | A_Child4       | Others
P001      | C_Child1       | Yes
P001      | C_Child2       | SomeValue
```

now it's possible to procede to `PIVOT`

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

WITH Q AS (
  SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + '_' + [Field] [Field], Value
       , ControlCode
       , ID = CASE WHEN [Field] = 'ControlPoint' THEN 1
                   WHEN [Field] = 'ControlScore' THEN 2
                   WHEN [Field] = 'ControlValue' THEN 3
              END
  FROM   (SELECT ProjectID
               , ControlCode
               , CAST(ControlPoint AS SQL_Variant) ControlPoint
               , CAST(ControlScore AS SQL_Variant) ControlScore
               , CAST(ControlValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlValue
          FROM Controls C) D
         UNPIVOT
         (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlPoint, ControlScore, ControlValue)) p
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + '_Child' + RowID [Field], Value
       , ControlCode
       , ID = RowID + 3
  FROM   (SELECT C.ProjectID
               , C.ControlCode
               , RowID = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CC.ControlID ORDER BY CC.ControlChildID) AS VARCHAR)
               , CAST(CC.ControlChildValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlChildValue
          FROM Controls C
               INNER JOIN ControlChilds CC ON C.ControlID = CC.ControlID) D
         UNPIVOT
         (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlChildValue)) p
)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Field])
                      FROM Q
                      ORDER BY ControlCode, ID
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')

SELECT @query ='
WITH Q AS (
  SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + ''_'' + [Field] [Field], Value
  FROM   (SELECT ProjectID
               , ControlCode
               , CAST(ControlPoint AS SQL_Variant) ControlPoint
               , CAST(ControlScore AS SQL_Variant) ControlScore
               , CAST(ControlValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlValue
          FROM Controls C) D
         UNPIVOT
         (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlPoint, ControlScore, ControlValue)) p
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ProjectID, ControlCode + ''_Child'' + RowID [Field], Value
  FROM   (SELECT C.ProjectID
               , C.ControlCode
               , RowID = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CC.ControlID ORDER BY CC.ControlChildID) AS VARCHAR)
               , CAST(CC.ControlChildValue AS SQL_Variant) ControlChildValue
          FROM Controls C
               INNER JOIN ControlChilds CC ON C.ControlID = CC.ControlID) D
         UNPIVOT
         (Value FOR [Field] IN (ControlChildValue)) p
)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ProjectID, [Field], Value FROM Q) AS t
       PIVOT 
       (MAX(Value) FOR [Field] IN( ' + @cols + ' )) AS p ;'

execute(@query);
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/438b5/25)</kbd>

To get the field in the wanted order that specific order must be forced in the columns string, so in the `SELECT ... FOR XML`, as there is no usable order column a new one need to be created, that the meaning of the `ID` in the `CTE`

Comment: Awesome! This also satisfies my need but I am very sorry that I can only select one answer. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @user972255  choose the one that you like more, or the one that you will use yourself, or the one that was written first ;-)